# jQGrid show sort icons always

Tags: jquery, sorting, jqgrid

I have a problem in jQGrid that when the column name is little large and if resizable set to false, it is not showing sort icons. In large monitors it is showing correctly . But in laptops and other small displays, it is hiding the sort icons. Can we wrap the title so it will be shown in next line along with the sort icons if the header text is large ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem which you describes was the main reason of the introduction of new option

```
sortIconsBeforeText: true
```

in [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid). The results you can see on the demo http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/qzxwfquq/4/ . I recommend you to add the option `headertitles: true` too. It allows the user to see the full text of the column header as tooltip:

[image]

Comment: This is awesome.   never knew such an option exists. Lifesaver.

Comment: @HappyCoder: The option is relatively new. It exist only in free jqGrid fork and it's introduced in version 4.9.1 (see [the readme](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/README491.md#the-following-bug-fixes-and-small-new-features-are-implemented-in-the-version-491)) published at the end of July. I want to start separate site with the documentation of free jqGrid, but still don't found enough time for it. I hope to publish it till the end of the year.

Answer (score 1):

```
.ui-th-column, .ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-htable th.ui-th-column {       
    white-space: normal !important;
}
```

This worked for me.